# Javascript to get text value from non end node HTML elements (such as an LI element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to write a script that will walk through an HTML source and create a JSON file of the DOM that will then be shown in a tree view using d3.js.  The problem I have is the desire to show not only the element (TITLE, P, LI, etc.) but also the value of the element.  This is easy enough IF I only do it for end node elements (no children). But, I sometimes need it for parent objects as in the UL below for items II and B.

```
        <ul class="level-1">
            <li>I</li>
            <li>II
              <ul class="level-2">
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B
                  <ul class="level-3">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>C</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>III</li>
        </ul>
```

From my function below this line is working for end nodes but I cannot figure out how to do this for parents without printing everything from every child.

```
   $output.append(', "value": "' + $(child).text() + '"}');
```

I have tried some first-child stuff from jQuery but could not get it to work.  I also want to keep this as generic as possible to feed in any html source.  In other words, I do not want to say if (nodeName = 'LI') then -do list item specific stuff-

```
  var createJsonOutput = function(domObject) {

    var $currentChildren = domObject.children();
    var $childrenCnt = $currentChildren.length

      $.each($currentChildren, function(idx,child) {
         $output.append('{"name": "' + child.nodeName + '"');

         //does the child have children?
         if ($(child).children().length > 0) {
                $output.append(',"children": [');
                createJsonOutput($(child));
                $output.append(']}');
         } else if (child.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA' && child.nodeName != 'SCRIPT') {
                $output.append(', "value": "' + $(child).text() + '"}');
         } else {
                $output.append('}');
         }

         if ((idx + 1) < $childrenCnt) {
            $output.append(',');
         }
      });
  };

  createJsonOutput($('html'));
```

EXAMPLE (unformated) JSON:

```
{"name": "HTML","children": [{"name": "HEAD","children": [{"name": "META", "value": ""},{"name": "TITLE", "value": "Node-Link Tree"},{"name": "SCRIPT"},{"name": "SCRIPT"},{"name": "LINK", "value": ""}]},{"name": "BODY","children": [{"name": "DIV","children": [{"name": "UL","children": [{"name": "LI", "value": "I"},{"name": "LI","children": [{"name": "UL","children": [{"name": "LI", "value": "A"},{"name": "LI","children": [{"name": "UL","children": [{"name": "LI", "value": "1"},{"name": "LI", "value": "2"},{"name": "LI", "value": "3"}]}]},{"name": "LI", "value": "C"}]}]},{"name": "LI", "value": "III"}]}]},{"name": "DIV","children": [{"name": "TEXTAREA"},{"name": "P", "value": "tree time!"}]},{"name": "DIV", "value": ""},{"name": "SCRIPT"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a function to return just text of the current element,

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() { 
    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();
};
```

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/02/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element.html

Comment: Thank you!  I needed to add a .trim() to the end of this but it works great.  My JSON looks correct now and I just need to modify the display code to output these values.

Answer (score 0):

children() only returns elements-nodes, but for example the II in the 2nd `<li/>` is a text-node.

You may use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead, it also returns text-nodes

Comment: I did not try this solution since Chamika's answer worked.  Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

I whipped something up that seems to do what you want.

```
function objectify(node, recursing) {
    var n, out = [];

    if (node.shift && node.shift.call) {
        while (n = node.shift()) {
            out.push(objectify(n, true));
        }
        return out;
    }

    n = {name: node.tagName};

    if (node.children && node.children.length) {
        n.children = objectify(out.slice.call(node.children), true);
    } else if (node.textContent) {
        n.value = node.textContent;
    }

    return recursing ? n : JSON.stringify(n);
}

// test it
console.log(objectify(document.getElementsByClassName('level-1')[0]));​
```

If I understand the problem you were having correctly, this avoids it by only getting the text content of a node if it has no children. You can probably apply the same thing to your code.

Output from running on your UL example above:

```
{"name":"UL","children":[{"name":"LI","value":"I"},{"name":"LI","children":[{"name":"UL","children":[{"name":"LI","value":"A"},{"name":"LI","children":[{"name":"UL","children":[{"name":"LI","value":"1"},{"name":"LI","value":"2"},{"name":"LI","value":"3"}]}]},{"name":"LI","value":"C"}]}]},{"name":"LI","value":"III"}]}
```

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/hCDjd/

Comment: No, the problem I am having is WANTING to include the text content even when there are children.  Your output mirrors mine (LI for II or B do NOT output the 'value' but I want it to).   But, I will look into the JSON.stringify and other things you are doing here to avoid my ugly concatenations of strings!  Thanks

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I thought your example JSON was what you wanted, not what you already had :)